# In-App Purchase product was set to an incorrect Purchasability Type.

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, review

My app was rejected because based on product functionality, please use the Non-Consumable In-App Purchase type. Non-consumable products are only purchased once by users and are always available on all devices that are associated with that user's iTunes account.

The item rejected is the consumable type, "buy one"

This is my response in the resolution center,

"I think there is a misunderstood with the functionality of the app.

Our apps consists in adding a design status bar to the wallpaper´s user. There are free and paid.

The user can purchase all once in a time "buy all", thats the non- consumable in app. (here all ok)

Or, the user can purchase only one status bar, "buy one", many times as he wants, because he is buying an item, "one status bar", as we have tons of items, and the user can get the times he/she wants,  we are still thinking thats a Consumable in app.

If we would name each of our more than 180 status bars, there will be 150 non consumable in app.

For example, would be the same such as fish food in a fishing app."

What do you think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the purchased status bar designed to "go away" once used? If not, it's non-consumable. The quantity of the item isn't the driving factor; it's the behavior of the item's use inside the app.

Comment: Yes, that status bar designed would be unlocked, but you can purchase another status bar with the same button "buy one"

Comment: Assuming each bar has its own SKU, which they should based on your description, you're still talking about non-consumable. It doesn't matter that you can buy/unlock a different one. In your own example, fish food, the fish food would go away/get used up as you feed the fish. The "thing" gets consumed to the point where there is no more if it. That doesn't match your status bar idea. Once purchased, the user can use that particular status bar indefinitely. That is the definition of non-consumable in this context.

Comment: If you're still convinced that you should be using consumable, try this exercise. A consumable item "goes away" and can only be "used" once. Explain how and why the bar goes away after the user "uses/consumes" it. Describe how and why the user understands that this item will only be available on this one device and how long the bar "lives" (indefinite is not an answer for consumable). If you can answer these questions in a way that makes sense, you may be correct, and can use these answers with the review team. If you can't answer them well, you still need to reconsider non-consumable.

Comment: Ok, I understand why it should be non-consumable . But if I set it as non-consumable, it could only be bought once and if the user wants another status bar it would say “you already bought this item” , as it’s non-consumable. How do you suggest I change it?

Comment: i can't make 150 non-consumable items, btw really appreciate the help!

Comment: Each individual bar requires its own SKU/id. Your catalog of available bars needs to reflect this behind the scenes and the user will purchase the SKU for the specific bar in question. Practically speaking, you may want to bundle bars together to reduce the number of individual items you have, but that's a business decision on your part. The technology to handle the SKU will effectively be the same whether you include one bar or 10.

Comment: Not being snarky: why can't you create that many? Application Loader can help by importing csv lists of item descriptions, but how you effectively manage large metadata sets is a separate question.